# Continuity of a function that is continuous separately

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is the function $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined as:

$f(x, y) = \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $ if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$

$f(x,y)=0 $ if $(x, y) = (0,0)$

Continuous in $(0,0)$?

I know that in respect of x and y separately f is continuous.

I was trying to find a curve that will prove that f is discontinuous but all curves that I try doesn't show f discontinuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$ then $$f(x,y) = \frac{r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta}{r} = \frac{1}{2}r\sin 2\theta$$

Alternatively: use $x^2 + y^2 \geqslant 2|xy|$ to get $|f(x,y)| \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Comment: I was thinking that $f$ must pass through 0, thanks for the answer